# javascript getHours & getMinutes - myHours & myMinutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, if-statement

have this:

```
let minute = timeSplit[0];
let today = new Date();
if (Math.abs(today.getMinutes() - Number(minute)) <= 5) {
  client.messages.create(
    {
      to: userPhoneNumber,
      from: "12055578708",
      body:
        "hello " +
        userNameString +
        ", \nYour training session just finished with " +
        trainerNameString
    },
    function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err: " + err);
      }
      console.log(data);
    }
  );
} else {
  console.log("not working");
}
```

what it does is get the current minute (ex. 45th minute of the hour), and subtracts it from the minute that is in my database. If my db `minute` is within 5 minutes of the current minute, then do the next part.

However, in my db I have both minute and hour stored. i need to check if the time in my db is within 5 minutes of the current time, including the hour. minute and hour are both just string values in my db. How can i do this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. You should look into getting the UNIX timestamp (epoch) which is in seconds or milliseconds sometimes, store that in your database and generate a new one. Then you can subtract the numbers and determine the time difference. Maybe that is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Zero i mean in a way yes. Maybe this will explain exactly what i am looking for. what it is doing right now is taking the minute in my db (Ex. 05), and the current minute, (57), and checking, is 57 - 05 <= 5. if it is, send text. if not, don't. so if the difference between the minutes is 5, then send. problem is, it is not checking for the hour as well. so if hour in db is 9, and hour now is 18, then it'll still send if its within the 5 MINUTE difference because i'm not checking for the hour. does that make more sense?

Comment: I think my solution will fix your problem. For example, the current UNIX timestamp is 1635989907. In 5 minutes it will be 1635990207. If you subtract those two numbers you get 300 seconds which is 5 minutes.

Comment: ohh i see what you're saying. totally makes sense, i think it'll work too . so the only issue i may see is that I have `hour` and `minute` as strings. so i am not sure how to convert them to unix timestamp in js. Going to do some research . If you already know how, feel free to share :)

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head. And if its possible, I recommend you migrate away from using only the hour and minute information that being stored and just use some sort of timestamps. UNIX timestamps are very nice since they are predictable, independent of time zones and easy to do math with (like calculating time in the future), but there are plenty of options.

Comment: I'm going to post an answer with that I was talking about to this post. If this is how you end up doing it and it is your solution, please mark it as such. Thanks :)

Comment: Convert the values for hour and minute to minutes (e.g. `dbMin = hour * 60 + Number(minute)` and compare to the current time in minutes `nowMin = new Date().getHours()*60 + new Date().getMinutes()` and if `Math.abs(dbMin - nowMin) <= 5` then the time is within 5 minutes of now.

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX timestamp is the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970. By using the current timestamp and subtracting it from one in the future or one in the past you receive a difference in seconds. From my understanding this is exactly what you need for your project. Code like this is what I imagine will be what you're aiming for:

```
/* JavaScript returns miliseconds so 
    we divide and round down to get seconds */
let now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); 

if(now <= (5 * 60)) { // Convert 5 minutes to 300 seconds
    // Send your message
} else {
    // Don't send message
}
```

Comment: This will check if `Date.now()` is between 00:00 and 00:05 (i.e. midnight and 5 minutes after midnight), it doesn't check the difference to some other time.

Comment: @RobG I'm not sure what you're talking about. I'm saying you need to convert your old time to a unix timestamp and then you can figure out the differences between them